# could not extract ResultSet error

Tags: spring, java-8, spring-data-jpa, postgresql-9.6, spring-orm

I am getting `could not extract ResultSet` error. I checked the repository method for a case where zero results were returned and everything seemed to work fine. I am unable to understand and reproduce the error. Any clues?

Following is my repository method where the error was reported -

```
@Query(value="select * from rsp_customer_post_snapshot main where exists (select 1 from (SELECT snap.post_id, max(snap.snapshotted_at) max_snap_at FROM rsp_customer_post_snapshot snap JOIN rsp_customer_post post on snap.post_id=post.post_id WHERE post.social_user_id = 123 AND snap.created_at >= '2017-11-01' group by snap.post_id) b where main.post_id=b.post_id and main.snapshotted_at = b.max_snap_at) ORDER BY main.created_at DESC", nativeQuery=true)
Collection<RecordSnapshot> findByUserIdAndCreatedAt(@Param("user_id") Long userId, @Param("created_at") Date createdAt);
```

Following is the error I got -

```
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy161.findBySocialUserIdAndCreatedAt(Unknown Source)
at com.myorg.rspdatacollector.services.social.SocialPostSnapshotService.findBySocialUserIdAndCreatedAt(SocialPostSnapshotService.java:38)
at com.myorg.rspdatacollector.services.social.SocialCollectorService.synchWithSocial(SocialCollectorService.java:101)
at com.myorg.rspdatacollector.services.social.SocialCollectorService.addDataForExistingSocialUsersNotSnappedToday(SocialCollectorService.java:176)
at com.myorg.rspdatacollector.services.social.SocialCollectorService.buildCustomerSocialStore(SocialCollectorService.java:141)
at com.myorg.rspdatacollector.application.ApplicationLoader.startJob(ApplicationLoader.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
... 26 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Check whether the columns returned by complex_join_query are available in RecordSnapshot entity

Comment: @shazin I have updated my query in my question. I tested the inner query within `exists` and even if it returns nothing, the outer query also returns empty recordset and everything seems to work fine in a psql client.

Comment: My inner query is just a EXISTS test while the WHERE clause in the outermost query uses the fields from the table.

Comment: Yeap also you are requesting a `Collection<RecordSnapshot>` , posting this class , would be helpful.

Comment: I had similar error and real cause was "eaten" by JpaSystemException. Do you have ability to debug the code execution and dig into exceptions thrown to get the real cause of this issue?

Comment: @AntJavaDev Here's the class RecordSnapshot https://gist.github.com/rgupta2/a15db1ac933d7f9cb78edfbec0c485e3

Comment: @AliakseiStadnik I have the ability to debug execution locally but I was unable to reproduce the error. I m thinking to enable trace logging for `org.springframework.orm.jpa` but i fear that would fill up my cloud hosted logging beyond limit as its a long running process and error cannot be predicted

Comment: hmm , from a fast look the class looks proper(supposing that the setters/getters exist, hibernate is used underneath and the `Date` field is of type `java.util.Date`). If its easy , replace the query with a native one to see what raw result set would be returned, before the mapping to entity happens.